# Maven not using configured repositories to resolve all dependencies

Tags: maven, gitlab-ci-runner

Hello I am trying to build a jar using maven behind a corporate proxy with our own artifactory server.

We are building using docker gitlab runners and I am using the *maven:3-jdk-8* image which is running *Apache Maven 3.5.4*.

The build starts fine by downloading the dependencies from our artifactory but when the maven-assembly-plugin tries to package our output into a jar I get the following error in debug mode:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2.1:single (package-jar-with-dependencies) on project <my-project>: Failed to create assembly: Unable to resolve dependencies for assembly 'jar-with-dependencies': Failed to resolve dependencies for assembly: Unable to get dependency information for org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.13.Final: Failed to process POM for org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.13.Final: Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-bom:pom:1.2.3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Name or service not known
[ERROR]   org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.13.Final
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
[ERROR]   central (https://artifactory.corp.net/, releases=true, snapshots=false)
[ERROR] Path to dependency: 
[ERROR]     1) <my-project>
[ERROR]     2) org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org: Name or service not known
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2.1:single (package-jar-with-dependencies) on project <my-project>: Failed to create assembly: Unable to resolve dependencies for assembly 'jar-with-dependencies'
```

The glaring issue would seem to be that maven is trying to retrieve hibernate-validator from `repo.maven.apache.org` rather than my local corporate artifactory.

I have verified that the jar in question does indeed exist in my artifactory. I have built the project locally (outside of docker maven version 3.6.1 bundled with Intellij) with identical settings and didn't have any problems.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

## Some possibly useful files

**The effective settings generated by help:effective-settings**

```xml
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">
  <localRepository>path-to-my-repo</localRepository>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <username>username</username>
      <password>***</password>
      <id>central</id>
    </server>
    <server>
      <username>username</username>
      <password>***</password>
      <id>snapshots</id>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>Artifactory</name>
          <url>https://artifactory.corp.net/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>Artifactory</name>
          <url>https://artifactory.corp.net/</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>Artifactory</name>
          <url>https://artifactory.corp.net/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>Artifactory</name>
          <url>https://artifactory.corp.net/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
      <id>artifactory</id>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
  <pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>org.apache.maven.plugins</pluginGroup>
    <pluginGroup>org.codehaus.mojo</pluginGroup>
  </pluginGroups>
</settings>
```

**The plugin configuration from the pom file**

```xml
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>the.main.class</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: The issue was this: `repo.maven.apache.org: Name or service not known` proxy/firewall or settings.xml file configuration...as JF Meier stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely that this is the result of a missing mirror configuration in the `settings.xml`.

If you want to send *every request* to your artifactory, you need to specify it as a mirror. Otherwise, repository definitions from POMs may be used as well.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I had tried a mirror previously but didn't get it to work. Your comment made me take another pass at it and that solved it by adding a mirror.